# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-(\cos 2x)^3(\cos 5x)^5(\cos 7x)^7(\sec 4x)^9(\sec 6x) ^{11}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-(\cos 2x)^3(\cos 5x)^5(\cos 7x)^7(\sec 4x)^9(\sec 6x) ^{11}}{x^2}$$

Now I can apply L'Hospital rule twice but believe it or not it would seriously be a very tedious task to do. I also tried writing $\cos 2x=\frac {e^{i2x}+e^{-i2x}}{2}$ and so on but couldn't continue due to large powers. Moreover I don't see any standard limits popping out.  The only sequence I could notice was in the powers of the trigonometric functions which follow the series $3,5,7,9,11$

Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what one calls a crafted problem especially designed to intimidate students. One of the easiest approaches is to use the Taylor series expansion (presented in another answer).

However the problem can be solved in step by step manner using the standard limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x} {x^2}=\frac{1}{2},\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}\tag{1}$$ Dividing the first limit by $\cos x$ and noting that $\cos x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ we can see that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sec x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$ Next we apply the usual algebraic technique of splitting to express the numerator $$1-abc\dots=1-a+a-abc\dots=1-a+a(1-bc\dots)$$ and note that each of $a, b, c\dots$ tends to $1$ as $x\to 0$. Thus the desired limit $L$ is equal to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^32x}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\cos^32x\cdot\frac{1-\cos^55x\dots} {x^2}$$ The first limit in above expression is evaluated by writing it as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^32x}{1-\cos 2x}\cdot\frac{1-\cos 2x}{(2x)^2}\cdot 4=3\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4=6$$ using standard limits $(1)$.

Thus $$L=6+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^55x}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\cos^55x\cdot\frac{1-\cos^77x\dots}{x^2}$$ The first limit above evaluates to $5(1/2)25=125/2$ and thus $$L=\frac{137}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^77x}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\cos^77x\cdot\frac{1-\sec^94x\dots}{x^2}$$ so that $$L=\frac{137}{2}+\frac{343}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sec^94x}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\sec^94x\cdot\frac{1-\sec^{11}6x}{x^2}$$ or $$L=240-9\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 16-11\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 36=-30$$ using limits $(1),(2)$.

Comment: Awesome, I’ll keep a deeper look to it!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try a Taylor series expansion around $0$, and notice you can throw away many terms.

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-(\cos 2x)^3(\cos 5x)^5(\cos 7x)^7(\sec 4x)^9(\sec 6x) ^{11}}{x^2} \\
&= 
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-(1-2x^2)^3(1-\frac{25}{2}x^2)^5(1-\frac{49}{2}x^2)^7(1+8x^2)^9(1+18x^2) ^{11}}{x^2} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-(1-6x^2)(1-\frac{125}{2}x^2)(1-\frac{343}{2}x^2)(1+72x^2)(1+198x^2)}{x^2} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-\left(1 + x^2\left(-6-\frac{125}{2}-\frac{343}{2}+72+198\right)\right)}{x^2} \\
&=-\left(-6-\frac{125}{2}-\frac{343}{2}+72+198\right) \\
&= -30
\end{align}$$

I used the facts that $\sec x = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$, $\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$ and $(1+t)^n = 1+tn + \mathcal{O}(t^2)$.

Comment: Tried that but was of no use. Could you elaborate your answer so that I could see which terms could be thrown away

Comment: @Manthanein updated

Comment: Did you just now use the binomial expansion below the Taylor series?

Comment: Yeah, precisely.

Comment: And  wait a minute how did you club the product into a single summation Or did you also approximate them to 0. Kind of looks weird to me practically but the procedure seems to be working pretty fine

Comment: The product is of the form $(1 + a x^2)(1 + b x^2)$, so up to $O(x^4)$ terms it is $1 + (a+b) x^2$.

Comment: If you're not fully convinced, add $O(x^4)$ terms (after almost everything I've written), and observe how they can all be neglected. I suspected this would work because the numerator is even, so the terms have even powers. The numerator is 0 at 0, so the constant term vanishes, so the next interesting term is $x^2$. If the $x^2$ coefficient was zero, the limit would be zero, so I knew to neglect any $x^4$ or higher terms.

Comment: No no its absolutely fine.  It's just that I have never practically used so much of approximation in limits so it is kind of new experience for me and the method used is great using the 'o' notation

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's Rule works and you need to use once only. After differentiating both the denominator and numerator, break it down into five parts.

The derivative of $1-\cos^32x\cos^55x\cos^77x\sec^94x\sec^{11}6x$ is

$$(6\cos^22x\sin2x)\cos^55x\cos^77x\sec^94x\sec^{11}6x\\
+\cos^32x(25\cos^45x\sin5x)\cos^77x\sec^94x\sec^{11}6x\\
+\cos^32x\cos^55x(49\cos^67x\sin7x)\sec^94x\sec^{11}6x\\
-\cos^32x\cos^55x\cos^77x(36\sec^94x\tan 4x)\sec^{11}6x\\
-\cos^32x\cos^55x\cos^77x\sec^94x(66\sec^{11}6x\tan6x)$$

Each part has a limit. (Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin kx}{x}=k$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan kx}{x}=k$.)

For example, $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{6\cos^2x\sin 2x\cos^55x\cos^77x\sec^94x\sec^{11}6x}{x}=12$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos^32x\cos^55x\cos^77x\sec^94x(66\sec^{11}6x\tan6x)}{x}=396$$

The limit is $\displaystyle \frac{3\cdot2\cdot2+5\cdot5\cdot5+7\cdot7\cdot7-9\cdot4\cdot4-11\cdot6\cdot6}{2}=-30$

Comment: I must admire your courage to differentiate a product involving so many factors. The problem is easily handled using Taylor series or by converting the product into a sum (as in my answer).

Comment: differentiation is easy by generalized product rule. It only looks awful but the rule is simple. I actually can directly give that answer $\frac{3\cdot2\cdot2+5\cdot5\cdot5+7\cdot7\cdot7-9\cdot4\cdot4-11\cdot6\cdot6}{2}=-30$ without writing down the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Rationalize the numerator and use $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y,\sec^2z=1+\tan^2z$

Also for $h\to0,\sin(ah),\tan(ah)\approx ah$

Comment: @manthanein, After the  replacements, ignore terms containing  $x^4$