# Could someone please explain the steps in the Maclauren series?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

> Find the limit of $$\lim_{x\to 0}{{1-(\cos x)({\cos2x})^{1/2}(\cos3x)^{1/3}}\over{x^2}}$$

Steps to solving this problem, from the book:

Step 1: $$\lim_{x\to 0}{{1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2})({1-2x^2})^{1/2}(1-\frac{9x^2}{2})^{1/3}}\over{x^2}}$$

Step 2: $$\lim_{x\to 0}{{1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2})({1-x^2})(1-\frac{3x^2}{2})}\over{x^2}}$$

Step 3: $$\lim_{x\to 0}{{1-(1-\frac{3x^2}{2})(1-\frac{3x^2}{2})}\over{x^2}}$$

Step 4:  $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1-1+3x^2}{x^2}=3 }$$

Could someone please explain to me, what happened in step 2. How did we loose the roots ? 
And what happened from step 2 -> step 3 I have no idea what happened there ... :(

Comment: Going from step 1 to 2... Your book seems to be using some sort of approximations which ... I don't know if it's legitimate, but it definitely doesn't *feel* right since I've never quite seen this in the context of limits. It seems even sketchier that they don't openly note that the approximations are being used. In any event, the approximations in question are below.

These follow for $x$ that are small in magnitude.

$$\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{3}$$

and generally, for the $n^{th}$ root,

$$\sqrt[n]{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{n}$$

Comment: Those approximations can be equivalently formulated by

$$(1+x)^n \approx 1 + nx$$

That said, I'm not sure what happened from step 2 to 3. (As it is I only know about the former approximations because they came up today in my course on modeling.)

Comment: The title mentions "the Maclauren series", which suggests you are doing a problem connected to a calculus class, but the body of the Question makes no clear connection to what material you might be expected to use to evaluate the limit.  Perhaps it is evident to you, but your Readers don't have the advantage of knowing this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably get rid of the book. Most calculus texts are like this. The right approach is to use the little / big o notation.

The key here is to use Taylor / Maclaurin expansions as $x\to 0$ $$ \cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\tag{1}$$ and $$(1+x)^n=1+nx+o(x)\tag{2}$$ where $o(f(x)) $ represents a function $g(x) $ such that $g(x) /f(x) \to 0$.

The starting step (based on expansion $(1)$ above) thus needs to be written like $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac {x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)\left(1-2x^2+o(x^2)\right) ^{1/2}\left(1-\dfrac{9x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)^{1/3}} {x^2} $$ and the next step (using $(2)$) becomes $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac {x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)\left(1-x^2+o(x^2)\right)\left(1-\dfrac{3x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)} {x^2} $$ Finally we have via multiplication $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\left(1-3x^2+o(x^2)\right)} {x^2}=3 $$

---

A simpler approach is to use standard limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x} {x^2}=\frac{1}{2},\,\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$$ which are equivalent to the Taylor expansions given earlier.

The numerator of the expression under limit is of the form $1-abc$ where $a, b, c$ all tend to $1$ as $x\to 0$. We can do a split like $$1-abc=1-a+a(1-bc)$$ and thus we have the desired limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x} {x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x\cdot\frac{1-(\cos 2x)^{1/2}(\cos 3x)^{1/3}} {x^2}$$ which is same as $$\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos 2x)^{1/2}(\cos 3x)^{1/3}}{x^2}$$ Applying the same technique we get $$\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos 2x)^{1/2}}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to 0}(\cos 2x)^{1/2}\cdot\frac{1-(\cos 3x)^{1/3}}{x^2}$$ The first limit above is evaluated as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos 2x)^{1/2}}{1-\cos 2x}\cdot\frac{1-\cos 2x}{(2x)^2}\cdot 4=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4=1$$ and thus desired limit is equal to $$\frac{3}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos 3x)^{1/3}}{x^2}$$ The last limit is evaluated in similar manner to get $3/2$ and thus the final answer is $3$.

This technique has been used for a more complicated problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2739873/72031).

Answer (score 4):

It's the generalized binomial theorem.
In its simplest form,
it states that,
for fixed $a$,

$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{(1+x)^a-(1+ax)}{x} \right)
=0
$.

Informally,
$(1+x)^a \approx 1+ax
$
or,
more precisely,
in big-oh notation,
$(1+x)^a = 1+ax+O(x^2)
$.

This follows from
L'Hopital's rule because

$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{(1+x)^a-(1+ax)}{x} \right)
=\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{a(1+x)^{a-1}-a}{1} \right)
=0
$.