# Find $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt[3]{1-x}\cdots\sqrt[2n+1]{1-x}}{x}} $ without using L'Hopital's rule.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $ n $ be a positive integer greater than $ 1 $.

Find : $$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt[3]{1-x}\cdots\sqrt[2n+1]{1-x}}{x}} $$

Without L'Hopital's rule or series expansion.

Here is What I did to solve the problem.

> \begin{aligned}\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{\displaystyle\frac{1-\prod\limits_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\sqrt[k]{1+\left(-1\right)^{k}x}}}{x}}&=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\displaystyle\frac{\prod\limits_{i=2}^{k-1}{\sqrt[i]{1+\left(-1\right)^{i}x}}-\prod\limits_{i=2}^{k}{\sqrt[i]{1+\left(-1\right)^{i}x}}}{x}}}\\&=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\displaystyle\frac{1-\sqrt[k]{1+\left(-1\right)^{k}x}}{x}\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=2}^{k-1}{\sqrt[i]{1+\left(-1\right)^{i}x}}}}\\ &=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}{\sqrt[k]{1+\left(-1\right)^{k}x}^{j}}}\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=2}^{k-1}{\sqrt[i]{1+\left(-1\right)^{i}x}}}}\\ &=\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k}} \\ &=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k+1}}-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k}}\\ &=-1+\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k+1}}+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k}}-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}}\\ &=-1+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}}-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}}\\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{\displaystyle\frac{1-\prod\limits_{k=2}^{2n+1}{\sqrt[k]{1+\left(-1\right)^{k}x}}}{x}}&=H_{2n+1}-H_{n}-1 \end{aligned}

What's your approach to solve the problem ?

Comment: Please include your approach in solving the problem that led to the result you said you got, showing your work, in an edit to your post.  I'm assuming you want to ensure that other answers show you a different approach than the one you use, so for the sake of saving potential answerer's time, please show your work and articulate your approach.

Comment: Fine @amWhy I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Chamsi!

Comment: Are you sure that's right?  I get $$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the derivative, the desired limit is equal to $-f'(0)$ where
$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt[3]{1-x} \sqrt[4]{1+x} \cdots \sqrt[2n+1]{1-x}.$$
We can now use logarithmic differentiation to find
$$f'(x) = f(x) \sum_{k=2}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} (1 + (-1)^k x)^{-1}.$$
Plugging in $x = 0$ and $f(0) = 1$ will give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial formula $$(1+(-1)^kx)^{1/k}=1+\frac{(-1)^k}kx+O(x^2),$$ so that
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=2}^{2n+1}(1+(-1)^kx)^{1/k}
&=\prod_{k=2}^{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}kx+o(x)\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=2}^{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}kx\right)+o(x)\\
&=1+x\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^k}k+o(x)
\end{align}$$
so that the desired limit is $$-\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^k}k$$

This differs from your answer.  Have I made a mistake?

Comment: it is the same as the author gets.

Comment: @saulspatz Did you saw the fourth line in my resolution ? It's the same result. I did just add some additional lines to express that sum in terms of the harmonic sequence.

Comment: @CHAMSI Sorry.  I skipped to the end of your post and then misread the formula.  Still, I answered the question, "What's your approach." -:)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the numerator is of the form $$1-abc\dots$$ where each of $a, b, c, \dots$ tends to $1$. We can rewrite the above as $$1-a+a(1-bc\dots)$$ and effectively the limit is converted into a finite sum of limits as $$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt[k]{1+(-1)^kx}}{x}$$ Clearly expression under limit above can be written as $$\frac{1-t^{1/k}}{1-t}\cdot\frac{1-t} {x}$$ where $t=1+(-1)^kx$ and the above tends to $$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$ and the desired limit equals $$-\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}(-1)^k\cdot\frac{1}{k}$$

---

This technique has been used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3414696/72031) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2739873/72031).